# how to delete duplicate records from a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, ms-word, arabic

i have a python script that extract data from tables in word file and convert it to dataframe  arabic text the problem is that when i try to display the dataframe it display each record twice and i can't delete the duplicate records.

## code:

```
import pandas as pd
import docx

document = docx.Document(path)
table = document.tables[0]

data = []

for row_index, row in enumerate(table.rows): # Loop through rows
    data.append([]) # Add container list for each row.
    for col_index in range(13): # Loop through columns 
        cell_text= row.cells[col_index].paragraphs[0].text.encode('utf-8')
        cell_decode_text = cell_text.decode('utf-8')
        data[row_index].append(cell_decode_text)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns=["group","person","category","source","dds","time","date","location","text","title","date_export","num_export",""]
df.drop_duplicates()
df.head(20)
```

## result:

```
 'date_export': {0: 'تاريخ الصادر',
  1: '',
  2: '2020/8/23',
  3: '2020/8/23',
  4: '2020/8/23',
  5: '2020/8/23',
  6: '2020/8/23',
  7: '2020/8/23',
  8: '2020/8/23',
  9: '2020/8/23',
  10: '2020/8/23',
  11: '2020/8/23',
  12: '2020/8/23'},
 'num_export': {0: 'رقم الصادر',
  1: 'رقم الصادر',
  2: '36015',
  3: '36015',
  4: '36016',
  5: '36016',
  6: '36017',
  7: '36017',
  8: '36018',
  9: '36018',
  10: '36019',
  11: '36019',
  12: '36020'},
```

Comment: Share example of duplicated rows in dataframe please, because standard method `df.drop_duplicates()` should work.

Comment: @ipj i edit my question and add the dataframe

Comment: It's better to paste result of `df.to_dict()` instead picture. I cannot replicate this picture in python.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set

`df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Using the dataset you've provided, the example below shows how using `df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)` does the job; as @Chinte also mentioned in their answer.

#### Before:

```
>>> df

    date_export     num_export
0   تاريخ الصادر    رقم الصادر
1       رقم الصادر
2   2020/8/23   36015
3   2020/8/23   36015
4   2020/8/23   36016
5   2020/8/23   36016
6   2020/8/23   36017
7   2020/8/23   36017
8   2020/8/23   36018
9   2020/8/23   36018
10  2020/8/23   36019
11  2020/8/23   36019
12  2020/8/23   3602
```

#### After:

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
>>> df

    date_export     num_export
0   تاريخ الصادر    رقم الصادر
1       رقم الصادر
2   2020/8/23   36015
4   2020/8/23   36016
6   2020/8/23   36017
8   2020/8/23   36018
10  2020/8/23   36019
12  2020/8/23   36020
```

Comment: i tried this but it did not work  and i displyed the result that i got  so is there an error in the iterating loop on the table

Comment: In order for `drop_duplicates` to work, the **entire** row must be duplicated. I presume there is at least one difference in the row.  Consider using the `subset` parameter of `drop_duplicates` and pass it a list of columns to use when identifying  duplicates.  [Docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).